# Анализ автообновляемых логов c Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Нужно организовать анализ логов, в которые чуть ли не каждую секунду добавляются строки. У меня появилось две проблемы:

1. После каждого перезапуска программы, она создаёт новый файл с логами в формате `<дата>_<время>.log`. Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы скрипт открывал именно последний лог файл?
2. Как можно сделать так, чтобы скрипт запоминал последнюю проанализированную строку и при следующем цикле начинал со следующей, пропустив предыдущие?

Мой код на данный момент:

```
while True:
  print('analyse logs...') 
  f = open('test.txt', 'r')
  logs = f.readlines()
  f.close()
  for line in logs:
    if ('executed' in line) or ('for test' in line):
      print(line)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: 1) Можно, получайте список файлов, парсите их названия, сортируйте, выбирая самый большой 2) После цикла `for` запоминайте `line` и при следующей итерации в цикле `for` пропускайте строки, что не равны той запомненной

Comment: @gil9red А можно поподробнее про запоминание `line`?

Comment: Сохраняйте последнюю строку в памяти. Это будет работать пока скрипт запущен. Либо сохраняйте в файле и при запуске приложения считывайте из файла. А так, создайте переменную `last_line` инициировав ее `None`, в цикле проверяйте что если `last_line is not None and last_line == line: continue`, тогда в цикле пропустите все строки, что не совпадают с последней запомненной. Сразу после цикла `for` обновляйте значение `last_line = line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> После каждого перезапуска программы, она создаёт новый файл с логами в
>   формате <дата>_<время>.log. Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы скрипт
>   открывал именно последний лог файл?

Нужно получить список файлов, распарсить их, и вытащить файл, чья дата наибольшая.
Я придумал файлы [с форматом](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) `%d%m%y_%H%M%S.log`:

```
logs/
    110220_113400.log
    130220_113400.log
    130220_120000.log
    131219_113446.log
```

А теперь парсим их названия:

```
import datetime as DT
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path

logs = glob('logs/*_*.log')
print(logs)
# ['logs\\110220_113400.log', 'logs\\130220_113400.log', 'logs\\130220_120000.log', 'logs\\131219_113446.log']

for file_name in logs:
    date_str = Path(file_name).stem
    print(date_str, DT.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d%m%y_%H%M%S'), sep=' -> ')
# 110220_113400 -> 2020-02-11 11:34:00
# 130220_113400 -> 2020-02-13 11:34:00
# 130220_120000 -> 2020-02-13 12:00:00
# 131219_113446 -> 2019-12-13 11:34:46
```

Код разбора имени в дату перенесем в отдельную функцию и используем ее в функции `max` для получения максимального элемента по дате:

```
def get_datetime_from_log_file_name(file_name):
    date_str = Path(file_name).stem
    return DT.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d%m%y_%H%M%S')

...

last_log = max(logs, key=get_datetime_from_log_file_name)
print(last_log)
# logs\130220_120000.log
```

---

> Как можно сделать так, чтобы скрипт запоминал последнюю
>   проанализированную строку и при следующем цикле начинал со следующей,
>   пропустив предыдущие?

Сохраняйте последнюю строку в памяти. Это будет работать пока скрипт запущен. Либо сохраняйте в файле и при запуске приложения считывайте из файла. А так, создайте переменную `last_line` инициируйте ее `None`, в цикле проверяйте, ее значение с текущей строкой и пропускайте строки, что не проходят ее. А после цикла `for` актуализируйте `last_line`.

Примерно так:

```
last_line = None

while True:
    print('analyse logs...')
    with open('test.txt') as f:
        logs = f.readlines()

    for line in logs:
        if last_line is not None:
            # Если текущая строка является последней, то сбросим флаг, чтобы не было
            # проверки last_line и продолжим разбор со следующей строки
            if last_line == line:
                last_line = None

            # Пропускаем текущие строки пока задан last_line
            continue

        if ('executed' in line) or ('for test' in line):
            print(line)

    last_line = line

    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Теперь каждый цикл стал выводить лишь одну нужную строку, что плохо, ведь между циклами может появиться несколько нужных строчек. Убрав `time.sleep` я выяснил, что закончив анализировать последнюю строчку, через один цикл начали появляться те же строчки заново, что также является проблемой, ведь между циклами нужных строчек может и не появиться!

Comment: @Mortmael, подправил, теперь действительно в `last_line` последняя строчка попадает