# Python неправильно сравнивает строки

Tags: python, парсер

Всем привет. [Вчера задавал такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082031/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-c-python). Теперь появилась такая проблема: потребовалось сделать так, чтобы последняя строка сохранялась в файл и при следующем запуске скрипта анализ логов начинался только после этой строки. Но python попросту неправильно сравнивает две абсолютно одинаковые строки.

Есть два файла: `last_line_log.txt`, содержащий последнюю строку, и `1.log` (собственно сам лог файл). 
Содержание `1.log`:

```
executed: test
executed: 1
executed: 2
executed: 3
executed: 4
```

Содержание `last_line_log.txt`:

`executed: 1`

Сам код:

```
import codecs
import time

#Создаю переменную last_line из текста с файла
try:
    last_line_f = open('last_line_log.txt', 'r')
    last_logfile_line = last_line_f.readlines()
    for line in last_logfile_line:
        last_line = line
    print(last_line)
except FileNotFoundError:
    last_line = None


while True:
    print('parsing logs...') 
    f = codecs.open('logs/1.log', 'r', "utf_8_sig")
    logfile = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    #Проверяю каждую строку
    for line in logfile:
            if last_line is not None:  
                if last_line == line:
                    #Именно тут проблема, ведь текст "test" не появляется
                    last_line = None
                    print('test')

                continue
            if ('executed:' in line):
                print(line)

    print('Done')
    last_line = line
    #Запись последней строки в файл
    last_line_f = open('last_line_log.txt', 'w')
    last_line_f.write(last_line)
    last_line_f.close()
    time.sleep(10)
```

В итоге у меня выходит:

```
executed: 1
parsing logs...
Done
```

Если убрать в самом начале try и оставить только `last_line = None`, то всё будет работать так, как и должно.

Comment: У вас просто жестокий способ получения последней строки из файла...

Comment: Зачем вам этот код? `    for line in last_logfile_line:
        last_line = line`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list вот тут можно посмотреть как получить последний элемент списка, море вариантов, но уж точно не перебирать весь список

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь в том то и дело, что мне нужно вывести все подходящие элементы из файла, а последнюю строку запоминать для того, чтобы при следующем цикле не появлялись предыдущие, а только новые, ведь файл автообновляемый...

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь я пробовал разные варианты, в том числе и `last_line = last_line_f.readlines()`, но ничего не помогает...

Comment: Это иллюзия.   >>>Если убрать в самом начале try и оставить только last_line = None, то всё будет работать так, как и должно.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь тогда как сделать нормально?

Comment: Если перед `if last_line == line:` напечатать в исходном виде строчки, например, используя функцию `__repr__`, так `print('last_line', last_line.__repr__(), 'line', line.__repr__())`
То на проблемном месте мы увидим `last_line 'executed: 1' line 'executed: 1\r\n'` и строки получаются совершенно неодинаковые, правильно замечено в ответе на вопрос. На будущее, как дебажить такие вещи, гораздо эффективнее, чем ждать ответа у сообщества, я считаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит, потому что в строках из файла `1.log` содержатся символы каретки и переноса строки. Чтобы исправить проблему достаточно использовать метод `strip()` строк. Так же я немного оптимизировал ваш код.

```
import codecs
import time

#Создаю переменную last_line из текста с файла
try:
    with open('last_line_log.txt', 'r') as last_line_f:
        last_line = last_line_f.readlines()[-1]
    print(last_line)
except FileNotFoundError:
    last_line = None


while True:
    print('parsing logs...') 
    with codecs.open('logs/1.log', 'r', "utf_8_sig") as f:
        logfile = f.readlines()

    #Проверяю каждую строку
    for line in logfile:
            if last_line is not None:  
                if last_line == line.strip():
                    #Именно тут проблема, ведь текст "test" не появляется
                    last_line = None
                    print('test')

                continue
            if ('executed:' in line):
                print(line)

    print('Done')
    last_line = line
    #Запись последней строки в файл
    with open('last_line_log.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(last_line)
    time.sleep(10)
```